# jquery if element contains number

Tags: jquery, numbers

I want to find out if an element contains a number no matter how long it is. I need a distinction between words and numbers or other characters.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/somaberlin/4P9CC/)

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Word</a></li> <!-- this is a word -->
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">...</a></li> <!-- this is a word -->
  <li><a href="#">15</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">30</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">100</a></li> <!-- this is a number -->
  <li><a href="#">Word</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4P9CC/3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [isNumeric](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isnumeric/) function for that.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4P9CC/4/)

```
$("li a").each(function() {
var num = $(this).text();
if ($.isNumeric(num)) {
        $(this).addClass('numb');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('noNumb');
    }
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4P9CC/5/)

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this by using REGEX

Reguler exp '**/\d/**'

**$(this).text().match(/\d/)**

```
$( "li a" ).each(function() {
    var matches = $(this).text().match(/\d/);
    if (matches){
       $(this).attr('class', 'numb');    
    }else{
       $(this).attr('class', 'noNumb');    
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4P9CC/3)

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. Use `isNaN` to check if it's a number or not.

```
$( "li a" ).each(function() {
    var xc = $(this).text();
    var isNum = isNaN(xc);
    if (isNum) {
            $(this).attr('class', 'numb');
        } else {
            $(this).attr('class', 'noNumb');
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as C-link said, isNumeric..

```
$("li a").each(function() {
var toCheck = $(this).text();
if (isNumeric(toCheck)) {
        $(this).attr('class', 'is_number');
    } else {
        $(this).attr('class', 'is_not_number');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "li a" ).each(function() {

var xc = $(this).text();

  if ( $.isNumeric(xc) ) {
    $(this).attr('class', 'numb');
  } else {
$(this).attr('class', 'noNumb');
  }
});
```